# Let's Encrypt setup for subdomain CDN

Tags: apache, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to setup a two server system, where one is doing webhosting and the another is delivering content (CDN) for the webhost server.

I currently own two servers and they both have Let's Encrypt SSL.

webhost https://example.com

```
example.com 123.123.123.123
```

CDN https://foo.com

```
foo.com 111.111.111.111
```

I already have setuped a subdomain to my webhost server:
`cdn.example.com`, which is pointing to the CDN server `foo.com 111.111.111.111`.

The problem is that the `cdn.example.com` does not have Let's Encrypt SSL.

**How can I get the Let's Encrypt SSL for the `cdn.example.com` which is pointing to the `foo.com 111.111.111.111`?**

When I run:

```
certbot --apache --cert-name example.com -d cdn.example.com
```

It gives an error:

```
Failed authorization procedure. cdn.example.com (http-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://cdn.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/PaKenmvAqHoOdOBUhThxxxxx: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML
2.0//EN\">\n<html><head>\n<title>404 Not Found</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Not Found</h1>\n<p"

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: cdn.example.com    Type:   unauthorized    Detail: Invalid response from    http://cdn.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/PaKenmvAqHoOdOBUhThxxxxx: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML
   2.0//EN\">\n<html><head>\n<title>404 Not    Found</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Not Found</h1>\n<p"

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was    entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain    contain(s) the right IP address.
```

Solved! **SOLUTION**: https://serverfault.com/questions/940178/lets-encrypt-setup-for-subdomain-which-is-pointed-to-other-host/940213#940213

Comment: When you request your certificate from Let's Encrypt SSL (which I have never used), you must ask for alternate names.  So the same certificate will be valid for example.com, www.example.com, cdn.example.com, ...  Depending how Let's Encrypt does that, they will either issue one with each alternate name explicitly listed, or provide a wildcard certificate (*.example.com).  See https://letsencrypt.org/docs/faq/, they do talk about Subject Alternative Name (SAN) and wildcard certs.

Comment: @Nic3500 thanks for the comment. I can successfully generate a SSL certificate to my subdomain, if the subdomain is pointed to the server itself where I'm generating it. But in this case, I'm trying to generate SSL certificate for my subdomain, which is pointing to the other server of mine.

Comment: No problem.  In your DNS entries, define example.com to IP1, cdn.example.com to IP2 and install the *same* certificate on both (since it is setup for both names).  If you have some king of automation (and you should since it's 90 days), you will have to replicate the same thing on both.  Or update it manually every 90 days (ouch!).

Comment: In my DNS entries, I have set the dns.example.com to my CDN server (foo.com) and it's working fine. But I can't generate the certificate for it (works only via normal http).

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood.  You say you have two server, so I expect you own them?  So in one of the servers, get your SSL certificate and specify an alternate name for **both** domain names.  The certificate will be on example.com with altername names www.example.com, foo.com, www.foo.com.  Setup the resulting certificate on both systems.

Comment: I'm not sure how I should proceed, I can't find instructions from Google. :\

Comment: Check with Let's Encrypt, it is down to what service they provide, and how.